# How to find 4th and 5th character of files name?

Tags: shell, ls, filenames, string

```
$ ls
abcmkde
ghemkde
vdecdde
```

For example I only want to list out file name with only 4 and 5th character with only one iteration of single match (`mk` and `cd` in the example above).

There is a bunch of files with different names and different fourth and fifth character.

Comment: With `zsh`: `(){printf '%s\n' ${(uM)${@#???}#??}} ?????*`

Answer (score 2):

Apply the Unix philosophy: one tool for each job, and the shell to combine them together. There are three jobs:

- List the file names. Unless your file names contain unprintable characters or control characters, this is a case where parsing the output of `ls` is reasonable. If you wanted to list only certain files, then you could use something like

  ```
  printf '%s\n' *.ext
  ```

  to list one name per line.
- Extract the part of the file name that you're interested in. To extract the 4th and 5th character, you can use `cut -b 4,5` (for single-byte characters) or `cut -c 4,5` (to allow multi-byte characters).
- Remove duplicates. The simplest way to do that is `sort -u` (this also sorts the parts).

[Pipes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing)) join the programs together. The result is

```
ls | cut -b 4,5 | sort -u
```

Answer (score 1):

With `ksh93`, `bash`, `zsh` or `mksh`:

```
for file in *; do
    printf '%s\n' "${file:3:2}"
done | sort -u
```

Comment: -bash: "*" : not a valid identifier
i tried replacing "file" to  "*" as i have more than 500 files. I tried keeping "file" as well and shows me error "-bash: "file" : not a valid identifier. I'm new to linux so please excuse silly question

Comment: Remove the quotes around `file`.

Comment: removed quote and gave me this output "{file:3:2}"
i'm executing this command at the same directory where all file listed.

Comment: Do you have `echo "{file:3:2}"` or `echo "${file:3:2}"`?

Comment: I had typo there. it worked. Thank you !!

Comment: would that give me 4 and 5th character of file name ? it doesn't seems like it would give me 3 and 2 character ?

Comment: The number after the first colon is the character at which to start.  Remember that the first character in the file name is the 0th, so `${file:0:1}` for a filename of `example` would be `e`. The number after the second colon is the number of characters to print.  You can test this with `foo='12345'; echo "${foo:3:2}"`.